# Android Lollipop view height doesn't fit screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm working on bringing an app that was targeting API level 18 up to support at least Lollipop level 21, however I've run into a graphical issue. When targeting API level 21+ the view seems to be too large for the screen, and the bottom of the app is truncated by the on screen buttons:

[image: API 18][image: API 21]

The XML is defined as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="..."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs" >

            </FrameLayout>

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
            </TabWidget>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone see what it is I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try changing android:layout_height="match_parent" to fill parent for your parent

Comment: @KaranMer I thought fill_parent was deprecated in API level 8? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html still seems to exhibit the same behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in v21 style.xml

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

You might also be interested about [this](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)

Comment: If only everything was this easy. Thanks!